# Bounding the Probability of the L^2-Norm

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-calculus

Let $Y$ be an random Variable, and $f(x,Y)$ be a measurable function.
I have for every $x\in[0,1]$

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(|f(x,Y)|\geq \varepsilon\right)\leq \delta
$$
Is there any chance to bound $\|f(.,Y)\|_{L^2_{[0,1]}}$ in probability by $C\varepsilon$ or something?

Comment: Any chance we can assume $f(x, y)$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes, i can assume first, that $\|f\|_\infty \leq c$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $m \le |f(\cdot, \cdot)| \le M$. By the reverse Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{align*}
\|f(\cdot, Y)\|_{L^2[0, 1]} \le C\|f(\cdot, Y)\|_{L^1[0, 1]}
\end{align*}
where $C = \frac{1}{4}\frac{(m+M)^2}{mM}$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\|f(\cdot, Y)\|_{L^2[0, 1]} \ge C\epsilon) \le \mathbb{P}(C\|f(\cdot, Y)\|_{L^1[0, 1]} \ge C\epsilon) \le \delta
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Could you explain where the last inequality comes from? Also unfortunatly i can not bound |f| from below.